# Navigation header is shown even though header:null is set

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation and I have tab based login/register. I also added *forgot password* button which leads to stack navigator.

In my login, the screen header is set to null. But it still shows a header. Maybe it is because of the stack navigator. But I still want to keep header in *forget password* screen so I have that "Back" button to go back to login/register tabs.

Here is my navigator if that is helpful:

```js
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  LoginStack,
  RegisterStack,
});

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs,
  ForgotPassword: {
    screen: ForgotPasswordScreen
  }
})

export default AppNavigator;
```

If you need any more info please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set `headerMode : none`  in navigation.

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  LoginStack,
  RegisterStack,
});

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs,
  ForgotPassword: {
    screen: ForgotPasswordScreen
  }
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
})

export default AppNavigator;
```

I hope this is work for you

Comment: That removes header in ForgotPassword screen as well, but I need it there so I can go back to login/register.

Comment: Then you can use native base custom header.
http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#header-def-headref